# How to create skype meeting request from Office 365 Web outlook?

Tags: office365, outlook-web-access, skype-for-business

How to create skype(skype for business 2016) meeting request using Office 365 Web outlook?

I could not able to install conference add-in for outlook web access(OWA). Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to initiate Skype meetings from OWA without the plugin. You need to fix the install issue first